# Account Team - Contact access doesn't list 'Read' in picklist

Tags: sharing, account-teams, manual-sharing

Users in my org, who are in top of the hierarchy are trying to give 'Read' access on contacts of an account, however they don't get the 'Read' LOV in the picklist 'Contact Access'. 
As an administrator I get that option, but not other users. Does any body know how that is controlled?
Account's OWD is Private.
Contact's OWD is Private.

[image: contact access only Private is available.]

As shown in the image, 'Contact Access' picklist shows only 'Private' option, it doesn't have Read or Read/Write option.

Comment: This might be a known issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008eZRAAY

Comment: It's not the case for my org, since OWD for oppty is set as private not read/write.